# Сохранение в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

На днях почти написал оконную программу для заметок на питоне с графическим интерфейсом (для ПК), осталось только сделать возможность сохранения, пример: Мы открываем программу, оставляем заметку со списком продуктов, после чего ее закрываем, ну и допустим выключаем ПК. Спустя какое-то время мы снова садимся за наш ПК открываем программу для заметок и там видим нашу заметку. Прошу посоветуйте какой-нибудь способ подобного сохранения или библиотеку.

Answer (score 2):

Смотря насколько увесистая программа. Если просто котики и для личного локального пользования без фанатизма то достаточно просто писать в фаил в какой фаил тут вариантов масса. Можно напрямую объект где хранятся заметки сохранять в фаил для этого есть прекрасная библиотека pickle не плохое описание тут [Клац клац и читаем](http://python-3.ru/page/module-pickle-python) Если надо хранить много и со статусами и прочим блэкжджеком и куртизанками то надо идти в строну простенькой бд SQLite для локального пользования. [SQLite неплохое простенькое описание клац](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/sqlite-v-python). Это из того что вот на изи всплывает в голове а так можно и джэйсон (json)примотать. Ну и входных данных мало  Если только хранить дела и по завершению стирать то pickle за глаза. Хотя в целом если охото хранить завершенные то можно их хранить в другом объекте но это всё костылики для небольших программулин, просто и быстро с минимумом доп изучения. Дядки посерьезнее писали бы с использованием SQLite

Comment: Благодарствую, pickle для моей ситуации отлично подойдет)